# Making a Form with the Right Alignment and Style

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to make this form in HTML/CSS:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO3Cr.jpg]

Unfortunately I can't seem to get the right style and alignment. I've been at it for hours now and whatever avenue I seem to take seems to get me nothing but garbage. Below is my best code, not very good, but it is what it is. Can anybody please help fix the code to reflect the above picture? I would truly appreciate it.

```
<style> * {
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .group:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    .containerANE {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #C6DEFF;
    width: 992px;
    }

    .rightANE {
     float: right;
     width: 30px;
    outline: 1px solid #8191a6;
    }
    .leftANE {
     float: left;
     width: 152px;
    outline: 1px solid #8191a6;
    }
    .middleANE {
     width:717px;
     outline: 1px solid #8191a6;
    }
</style>


<h1>E-mail US</h1>
<form action="file:///C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/confirmed.php" method="get">
<div class="group containerANE">
<div class="group rightANE">
<img width="25" src="http://i.imgur.com/881g5D7.png">
</div>
<div class="group leftANE">
 Name
 </div>
 <div class="group middleANE">
 <input type="text">
 </div>

<div class="group rightANE">
 <img width="25" src="http://i.imgur.com/881g5D7.png"> 
 </div>
 <div class="group leftANE">
 Description 
 </div>
 <div class=middleANE>
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50">

</textarea> 
 </div>


<div class=rightANE>
 <img width="25" src="http://i.imgur.com/881g5D7.png"> 
</div>
<div class=leftANE>
E-mail<br><br>Phone
</div>
 <div class=middleANE>
<input type="text">
<br> OR <BR>
<input type="text">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
```

[This is a representation of the code in JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jd4V7/)

Comment: First of all... Welcome to stack overflow.... Can you show right now what you are getting??

Comment: What exactly is your specific problem? Your code is very far from looking even close to that image - can you narrow down the particular problem. Apart from, "it doesn't look the same, please make it look the same."

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am getting right now http://i.imgur.com/WZ8iy3c.jpg

Comment: @RonakBhatt The OP isn't using tables?

Comment: use border in style tag accordingly in divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/2ed5t/) will give you a start.

HTML

```
<table class='holder'>
  <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type='text' size=40></input></td>
      <td><div class='icondiv'></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Desscription:</td>
      <td><textarea rows=6 cols=31></textarea></td>
      <td><div class='icondiv'></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input type='text' size=40></input></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan='3' id='single'>or<div id='singlediv' class='icondiv'></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Phone:</td>
      <td><input type='text' size=40></input></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan='3' id='single'><input type='submit'></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS is a bit long, and it's in the fiddle in any case.

Play with the CSS to refine it to your needs.